# How can I solve this MySQL and Python problem?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\josej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 553, in config
DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION[key]
KeyError: 'datebase'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\josej\proyectos\holamundo\curso\db.py", line 3, in 
midb = mysql.connector.connect ( host="localhost", user="josejan21", password="123JOSE123jan@gmail", datebase="prueba")
File "C:\Users\josej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector_*init*_.py", line 272, in connect
return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\josej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 94, in **init**
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\josej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1049, in connect
self.config(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\josej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 555, in config
raise AttributeError("Unsupported argument '{0}'".format(key))
AttributeError: Unsupported argument 'datebase'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your code, in the mysql connect method you are passing in "datebase" instead of "database" as an argument.

Comment: Excuse me, but could you explain to me how to solve the problem?

Comment: There's a mistake in the mysql connect method,                                                                                         `midb = mysql.connector.connect ( host="localhost", user="josejan21", password="123JOSE123jan@gmail", datebase="prueba")`.  It should be `database` not `datebase`

Comment: Great thank you very much I had already corrected that error but it seems that it was not saved, really thank you very much